# Simplify sum of two opposite integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

The following expression is not being simplified to zero (*Mathematica* 10.0)

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] + Integrate[-f[x], {x, a, b}]]
```

I think that this is due to possibility that one of the integrals may diverge. How do I tell *Mathematica* that the integrals are convergent, so it could combine the integrands together?

UPD. Ideally a rule for combining integrands together will be just fine
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_a^b g(x) dx \mapsto \int_a^b f(x) + g(x) dx
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can add your own transformation rules. For example:

```
newTransform[expr_] := 
 expr /. {HoldPattern[
     Integrate[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] + Integrate[-f_, {x_, a_, b_}] + 
      any___] :> Integrate[f - f, {x, a, b}] + any}

FullSimplify[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] + Integrate[-f[x], {x, a, b}],
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, newTransform}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] + Integrate[-f[x], {x, a, b}] /. 
Integrate[expr_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, rest__] :> -Integrate[-expr, rest]
   0
```

Comment: But this probably won't fork for $\int f(x) dx + \int g(x) - f(x) dx$?

Comment: Well, that **isn't** the case you presented in the OP, no? :) You'll need to program in the linearity rules yourself if so.

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
rule = Integrate[g1__, {x, a_, b_}] + Integrate[g2__, {x, a_, b_}] :> 
   Integrate[Simplify[g1 + g2], {x, a, b}];
```

and then:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] + Integrate[-f[x], {x, a, b}] /. rule

(*  0  *)
```

Have fun!